# eliminate duplicates in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to pick up 3 random numbers out of a list of 20 numbers.

In views.py, I've defined this variable:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

In my template index.html:

```
{{ nums|random }} - {{ nums|random }} - {{ nums|random }}
```

I want to get 3 different numbers, but I don't know which filter/tag to apply.

I've tried if/else statements, for loops, (if there's a duplicate I want a redraw) but i'm not satisfied with the results and I'm pretty sure there's a simple filter to do that.

Comment: Are you using `nums` list for other purposes than picking random numbers? If not, can shuffle the nums list upfront and just pick the first 3 elements.

Comment: I'm using the list only to pick up random numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a reasonable way to do this with the built in filters. I'd just pick the numbers in the view and pass that in to the context.

If your rendering is consistent and you want to do this a lot of places you could write a custom template tag, eg:

```
import random
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def random_sample(population, k):
    return ' - '.join(str(choice) for choice in random.sample(population, k))
```

Then `{% random_sample nums 3 %}` in your template.

But I think doing it in the view is simpler.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDeGlopper. I'm new to Django and this solution which i'm sure is working is too advanced for my current level. I'm gonna read the documentation about custom tags though. That's a good thing for me to know that i can dig into that direction.

Comment: They're one of the general answers to "I want to do something that's too advanced for the built in template tags and filters". The other is to just do it in the view and pass the result to the template.

Comment: Thanks a million for the feedback, i've read the django documentation to understand your help about custom template tags. And not only i've succeeded in making my code work (added the __init__.py file, load the custom tag etc.) but also, and maybe more important, you made me realize and understand the power of django! I realize that i can do a lot more than i thought in the first place.  Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

You could create your templatetag with this functionalitiy to solve your problem.

yourapp/templatetags/custom_choice_tags.py

```
from django import template
import random

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_three_unique_random_values_from_list(value_list):
    random_choices = random.sample(value_list, 3)
    selected_choices = {
        'first_choice': random_choices[0],
        'second_choice': random_choices[1],
        'third_choice': random_choices[2],
    }
    return selected_choices
```

and then in your template.html:

```
{% load custom_choice_tags %}

{% get_three_unique_random_values_from_list random_list  as random_choices %}

 {{ random_choices }}
```

the variable random_list would be passed from your view into the template context in this example.

Comment: Just use random.sample rather than tbe indefinite duration while loop, that's what it's for.

Comment: thx @PeterDeGlopper for pointing that out I did not know about random.sample before!

Comment: Thanks @matyas i appreciate the feedback. I'll look into custom tags solution then.